# Need help converting something from urllib2 to urllib3

Tags: python, urllib, urllib2, urllib3

I am trying to adapt the functions below from urllib2 to urllib3.  The problem I am running into is that urllib3 does not have the openurl attribute.  How would I rewrite these functions?

Thank you in advance.

def get_season_URLs(year) :

```
if not year in VALID_YEARS :
    print (str(year) + " is an invalid year")
    return
base_url_schedule_1 = BASE_URL + "/leagues/NBA_" + str(year) + "_games-"
url_extensions = YEAR_ONE_MONTHS + YEAR_TWO_MONTHS    
urls = []

for extension in url_extensions :
    schedule_url = get_schedule_URL(year, extension)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(schedule_url).read(), "html.parser")
    schedule_table = doc.find_all("tbody")[0]
    box_score_els = schedule_table.find_all(attrs={"data-stat": "box_score_text"})

    for el in box_score_els :
        urls.append(BASE_URL + el.find("a").get('href'))
return urls
```

def scrape_game(url, f) :

````
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
doc = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
if not len(doc.find_all(attrs={"data-label":"All Games in Series"})) == 0 :
    return False
line = ""```
````

Answer (score 0):

You're using BeautifulSoup, so I'm going to guess that you're using python2.7:

```
try:
        from urlllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
        from urllib import urlopen
```

And change `urllib2.urlopen` to just plain `urlopen` in your call.

In python3, you'd change the second `from` to read `from urllib.request import urlopen` but you'd have to change the `BeautifulSoup` call into the appropriate python3-ism.